# How to send maltipart/formdata from react to nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, react-redux, axios

Hi I am new in MERN development world. I am trying develop my first MERN APP, till text input from browser I have created. Now I am stucked at the file input.

***File field is working fine at frontend but in api the file field is empty but rest of the fields are working well...
In browser before api call photo/ file is there but in the api req.body or req.file no data.
I have used multer which is working fine.***

Please help me, I trapped here.

***Frontend Code***

```
export const register = ({ name, email, password, password1, photo }) => (dispatch) => {
  // Request body
  const body = { name, email, password, password1, photo };
  /*console.log(photo); //gives the desired output...*/
  axios.post('/api/users/register', body)
  .then(function (res) {
    dispatch(returnStatus(res.data, res.status, 'REGISTER_SUCCESS'));
    dispatch({ type: IS_LOADING })
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    dispatch(returnStatus(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'REGISTER_FAIL'))
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_FAIL
      });
      dispatch({ type: IS_LOADING })
  });
};
```

***Serverside code***

```
exports.registerUser = (upload.single("photo"), (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password, password1 } = req.body;
  console.log(req.file,req.body);
  if(password != password1) return res.status(400).json("Passwords missmacth.");
  const result = registerSchema.validate({ name, email, password});
  if(!result.error) {

      // Check for existing user
      User.findOne({ email: email }).then((user) => {
        if (user) return res.status(400).json("User already exists");
        //New User created
        const newUser = new User({
          name,
          email,
          password,
          password1
        });

        //Password hashing
        bcrypt.genSalt(12, (err, salt) =>
          bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            newUser.password = hash;
            bcrypt.hash(newUser.password1, salt, (err, hash) => {
              if (err) throw err;
  
              newUser.password1 = hash;
              // Save user
              newUser
                .save()
                .then(
                  res.json("Successfully Registered")
                )
                .catch((err) => console.log(err));
                })
          })
        );
      });
  } else {
    res.status(422).json(result.error.details[0].message);
  }

});
```